# PHP appends zero to response when http connection header is set to 'close'

Tags: php, http-headers

If I make an HTTP request to a PHP script on my server and include the HTTP 'connection' header with a value of 'close', the response from the PHP script contains a couple of new lines and a zero.

I've tried making a request for a flat file and the zero is not appended to that, so I'm pretty sure its PHP not Apache, but who knows.

I've tried making the request from Firefox, which doesn't send the connection close header and the zero is not present.

Does the HTT Protocol specify a connection close header? Does it specify what a server should append a zero to a response when it receives one?

---

Edit: This problem on appears when using HTT Protocol version 1.0, but not when I use 1.1

---

Edit: Turns out it was the Fortinet firewall causing this problem. I'll answer this properly when I have a full solution.

Comment: I suspect PHP is sending the response in `chunked` format. The last chunk in a response is indicated with a length of `0`.

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)